# How do I store non-serializable data between page postbacks in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate, serializable

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I've searched without finding an answer.

I need to store some non-serializable data between postbacks in ASP.NET. `ViewState` does not work, but `Session` does, but it seems as if it's bad practice to store non-serializable data in a session.

Does anybody have any advice on how I can do this?

Edit:

Example:

```
HtmlGenericControl dinaDiv3 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
dinaDiv3.ID = "dinaDiv3";
oneDiv.Controls.Add(dinaDiv3);

Control[] str = new Control[oneDiv.Controls.Count];
oneDiv.Controls.CopyTo(str, 0);

ViewState["test"] = str;
```

Throws:

```
Type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the non-serializable data, or the scenario you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dimo, when you are trying to store a ControlCollection to reuse it later, it doesn't seem a best practice to me. Maybe you should just store the information you need to recreate them.

Comment: That's a good point! I will try that. Would still love to know how the best way to store non-serializable data is :)

Comment: @André Pena, actually it's not possible, since I need to maintain the order of objects in the control..

Comment: @Dimo, then just serialize the order to the view or session, when you maintain the data used to create the controls.